# Loop to save value from a select multiple

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core, foreach

I have a select that now needs to select and save more than one option. His FrontEnd part is already done, but BackEnd is not.

I need this select to save the selected values, for that it will need to loop the code, because at the moment it only saves one value.

However I don't know how to loop this code so that it saves all values ​​and stops giving an error.

***Screen with the selected values ​​and their codes:***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5Xqu.png)

***Select html code:***

```
<div class="form-group pmd-textfield">
    <label for="TipoPenalAntecedenteCriminal" class="espacamentoLabels">
      Tipo Penal Principal
    </label>
    <select asp-items="Model.ListTipoPenal"
     name="COD_TIPO_PENAL_PRINCIPAL"
     id="TipoPenalAntecedenteCriminal"
     form="formAntecedenteCriminal"
     class="select-codigo" multiple
     onchange="mostrarOutroDeCombo(this, 'OutroTipoPenalAntecedenteCriminal');">
          <option value="">Selecione a relação</option>
     </select>
 </div>
```

***Code Controller:***

this is the code that I need to loop to save all values

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SalvarAntecedenteCriminal(IFormCollection form)
        {
            #region GET DADOS DO USUARIO
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
            string usuarioLogado = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            #endregion

            _logger.LogInformation(EventosLog.Get, "Usuário: {Usuario} | Salvando Antecedente criminal de autor com o código {codigo}.", usuarioLogado, form["COD_AUTOR"]);

            string codAntecedente = string.IsNullOrEmpty(form["COD_AUTOR_ANTECEDENTES_CRIMINAIS"]) ? "0" : (string)form["COD_AUTOR_ANTECEDENTES_CRIMINAIS"]
                , codUF = string.IsNullOrEmpty(form["COD_UF"]) ? "0" : (string)form["COD_UF"]
                , codTipoPenal = string.IsNullOrEmpty(form["COD_TIPO_PENAL_PRINCIPAL"]) ? "0" : (string)form["COD_TIPO_PENAL_PRINCIPAL"];

            DateTime? ocorrenciaData = string.IsNullOrEmpty(form["OcorrenciaData"]) ? null : (DateTime?)DateTime.Parse(form["OcorrenciaData"]);

            var antecendeteCriminal = new AutorAntecedentesCriminaisModel
            {
                COD_AUTOR = int.Parse(form["COD_AUTOR"]),
                COD_AUTOR_ANTECEDENTES_CRIMINAIS = int.Parse(codAntecedente),
                OcorrenciaNumero = form["OcorrenciaNumero"],
                COD_UF = int.Parse(codUF),
                OcorrenciaData = ocorrenciaData,
                COD_TIPO_PENAL_PRINCIPAL = int.Parse(codTipoPenal),
                OutroTipoPenal = form["OutroTipoPenal"]
            };

            try
            {
                antecendeteCriminal.COD_AUTOR_ANTECEDENTES_CRIMINAIS = antecendeteCriminal.Insert(usuarioLogado);
            }
            catch (Exception excecao)
            {
                _logger.LogError(EventosLog.FormularioSalvarErro, excecao,
                    "Usuário: {Usuario} | Falha ao salvar antecedente criminal de autor com o código {codigo} devido à exceção.",
                    usuarioLogado, form["COD_AUTOR"]);

                if (_env.IsDevelopment())
                    throw;

                return Json(null);
            }

            return Json(antecendeteCriminal);
        }
```

Code image, the part in yellow and where the error hits when saving.

In "**COD_TIPO_PENAL_PRINCIPAL = int.Parse (codTipoPenal),**" it is receiving the values, but it is not saving.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtFvN.png)

Comment: `codTipoPenal.Split(',')` gets you the array, then loop that?

Comment: @Charlieface Yes. Because at the moment it saves only one value "5" of the codTipoPenal, I need it to loop and keep saving the other values.

Comment: So just loop that array `for each (var item in codTipoPenal.Split(',')) {...int.Parse(item)...  }`

Comment: @Charlieface I didn't understand how it would look, could you explain it better please?

Comment: You need to run the code `var antecendeteCriminal = new AutorAntecedentesCriminaisModel.... antecendeteCriminal.Insert...` in a `foreach` loop over your split string. For each one, pass the loop variable in `COD_TIPO_PENAL_PRINCIPAL`

Comment: @Charlieface Could you show me an example of how it would look please?

Answer (score 0):

The `COD_TIPO_PENAL_PRINCIPAL` should be a int array if you wany to save all the values.

```
public int[] COD_TIPO_PENAL_PRINCIPAL { get; set; }
```

[image]